# Channels overwrote my SE image with my SO image

Tags: bug, status-completed, images, stack-overflow-for-teams

#### Backstory

I have one picture for Stack Overflow (Gravatar style) and another one which is visible on the whole of Stack Exchange (my face).

When I signed up to channels it showed me my SO image (Gravatar style) and my username and asked if I wanted to change it. I continued without changing anything and was brought into channels. So far, so good.

#### The Problem

This morning I realised that my profile image on all SE sites has been *replaced* by my image from SO so that I have a single image (Gravatar style) across the whole network instead of one for SO and another for SE.

---

#### Things to note

Just to make things more confusing, the 'Gravatar style' image was not my actual Gravatar image. I took a screenshot of the old one and uploaded [when the Gravatars changed](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/332880/why-did-my-avatar-change). I only mention this because it may point to a different issue.

For clarity, I am not having an issue uploading a new profile image and choosing between 'global' and 'just for this community', this is an issue that happened when I signed up for a private channel.

This is a different question to [Wrong avatar on Channels](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364358/wrong-avatar-on-channels) because that relates to the process of *changing* your image rather than the image being overwritten everywhere.

Comment: The other issue is not related to changing your image. I got the wrong image, too; but just on Channels. I have the same avatar everywhere.

Comment: s/avatar/profile picture/ actually, just to be consistent with the terminology here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Teams profiles and the Stack Overflow profile are always kept in sync, but a bug in the sync process was also propagating profile changes to the entire network. This issue has now been fixed, thanks for your report.