# Joining a Team forces my Stack Overflow identity to match my real name

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, privacy

I've been invited to join a [stackoverflow-for-teams](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow-for-teams). On the “Finish creating your Team profile” screen, I'm asked to select an avatar and a name, and told:

> Avatar
>   This will also update your Stack Overflow public account avatar.
>
> Full Name
>   This will also update your Developer Story and any other Teams you may have joined.

This mixes at least three different identities and I'm puzzled as to what the connection is supposed to be. There's:

- My “developer story” name, i.e. the name I'd use when looking for a job.
- My identity on Stack Exchange, through my avatar.
- My name on the team I'm joining.
- My name on other teams that I've joined.

My identity on Stack Exchange and the identity I use when looking for a job are different. So it seems that I can't join a team. Surely this isn't desired behavior?

(If I have to tie my Stack Exchange identity to my legal name, I'm out of here.)

I think this is partially a duplicate of [My public display name in a Channel shouldn't be tied to my Private Information Full Name](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364664/my-public-display-name-in-a-channel-shouldnt-be-tied-to-my-private-information) but I'm not sure whether we're talking about the same thing and that earlier question doesn't consider all the identities involved.

Why doesn't this screen just ask me to select a name and avatar, and *not update anything outside the team I'm joining*?

Comment: Yeah, this is super annoying. I just changed my real name to the name folks know me by and gave up using my legal name anywhere on SO.

Comment: Wait your given name at birth wasn't Shog9?

Comment: @DavyM he evolved overtime from Shog1 to Shog9.

Comment: Oh okay I thought he was a 9th generation Shog. I'm glad to get that cleared up.

Comment: The real question is if he's from outer space.

Comment: I just deleted my only team because of this :-/

Comment: This is literally the only thing stopping me from joining the mods team.

Comment: After 40-50 years of people using pseudo-anonymous avatars for online interaction, it's amazing to me how many supposedly internet-savvy companies repeatedly [screw this up](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nymwars). And I say this as someone who generally uses my legal name online!

Comment: @Boaz especially since it's a monetization avenue...

Comment: If joining a team *really* does this, as opposed to this being a misunderstanding, how could even a junior programmer write the messages quoted above without raising a red flag for the team / management?! A designer wireframing it? A tester testing it? The sheer number of people who had to be complicit, at least by omission, in enabling that behavior -- again, if it's really there -- truly boggles the mind.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: If everyone involved is under 30 I'm not surprised. People these days have grown up with different expectations of online identity. I blame Facebook. I don't even understand why people trust LinkedIn

Comment: I don't use Teams, but this would be a problem for me as well.

Comment: @slebetman I'm over 40 and use my real name on SO, and in some other websites as well (I don't have a Facebook account, though). Just never seemed to me like there is something to hide...

Comment: @slebetman `why people trust LinkedIn` I do/did if you can convince why not too?

Comment: @ZoharPeled: If you were on the internet in the 90s or early 2000s the standard advice is to never reveal anything about yourself IRL because it is extremely dangerous. Therefore a lot of the people I myself know online I only know via nicknames. It was considered insane back then to reveal any detail that might lead to actual details about yourself IRL. Actually things have not improved. It is now much worse to reveal details about yourself. That's the whole point of doxing. It's just people got used to it. All my employees use their real names online.

Comment: @RobertPounder: Because you are revealing not only your real name but also where you work and where you are physically in the world. That notion is crazy to me

Comment: @slebetman "because it is extremely dangerous." What's so dangerous about that? Are you worried someone will not like something you wrote on SO and come to your house at midnight with a baseball bat? Personally, I think some things are better left outside the internet, but extremely dangerous seems like paranoia to me.

Comment: @Boaz Yeah, I get that the point of the post is different then what I'm asking about, I even agree with the claim that people should get to keep their secret online identities, I'm just curious as to why slebetman thinks it's extremely dangerous to expos one's real name online.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Did your parents not tell you to "not talk to strangers" when you were a kid? [Want some candy?](https://i.ytimg.com/vi/sGb0rxA2FW4/hqdefault.jpg)

Comment: @Draco18s Not the same thing, IMHO.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Actually it is. Back when "chat rooms and message boards" were first starting to exist my parents didn't want me using them for the exact same reasons used for "don't talk to strangers."

Comment: Well, I'm not a child anymore, so I don't think someone might seduce me with free candy into their van (I think I was too smart for that as a child as well). Your parents are entitled to their own opinion, of course, but I personally don't see how talking with strangers on the internet is so extremely dangerous for grownups... I think I have a better chance of getting hit by a car then of getting hit by someone on SO...

Comment: Google, Facebook, etc. - they came not to praise the old Internet culture, but to bury it.

Comment: @ZoharPeled "extremely dangerous" - several things used to be easy to do by simply knowing my real name and some details about myself 1. stealing my money can be done via social engineering 2. stealing my identity can similarly be done (a bit harder in my case because we have a national identity database) 3. robbing my house (yes, this does happen) 4. swatting etc.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Now, what does that have to do with StackOverflow? Not much except the stealing money and identity thing. But it's like the Unix mentality about security - assume everything is going to be hacked and protect everything, be paranoid vs the old DOS mentality about security - nothing is important and has no security implications so chill, except this banking app, this app will implement custom security (then along comes some malware that undermines that security)

Comment: Wow, **still** no actual reply from SE?

Comment: @slebetman One point for using your real name is that it makes you think twice before writing something you don't want people like your friends, family, and co-workers to be able to tie back to you. It forces you to behave more nicely then if you only used a nick that can't be traced back to you (easily).

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's done now.

Comment: @ZoharPeled Many people with a nickname have a reputation to protect that is unique beyond what a common name would be, thinking that everyone uses sock-puppets to justify saying bad things is not a strong argument.

Comment: @KalleMP Perhaps it's not a strong argument for SO users, but you should see what social networks looks like. 
BTW, you're replying to a comment from May 2018, that's over 4 years old.

Comment: I am out if I have to reveal my identity with my Stackoverflow identity. I found hiding information is the best way to speak from the heart without fear of being caught, messing up relationships, or being fired.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

We shipped a change today that completely separates your Stack Overflow public profile from your Teams profiles.

1. We added a site switcher dropdown to the Edit Profile page so that users with Teams can customize their profile per team.  We do not sync any settings on this page between Stack Overflow public and Teams. Updating your Real Name on Stack Overflow public does not update your display name nor real name on your Teams.
   [image]
2. The "Finish creating your Team profile" page during Teams onboarding does not sync the avatar and full name to the Stack Overflow public profile.

Comment: Thank you! Can you confirm that the team profile is also independent from the developer story?

Comment: @Gilles correct. Changes to a Teams profile does not affect developer story.

Comment: Is this still valid in 2022? I can't seem to find the dropdown to edit my profiles, despite both using the same email adress.

Answer (score 42):

So... I commented when this was posted, but it deserves a real response.

First of all, this is a legitimate concern, and not *just* on those rare Teams composed of various people from The Internet who normally know each other by pseudonym; it's *extremely* common for groups of co-workers to adopt nicknames, short names, etc. simply to make working together easier:

- co-workers may share first names or even initials
- co-workers may find using full names cumbersome
- cultural reasons that I'm not really qualified to comment on but have encountered in various workplaces
- some names may simply be hard to pronounce or remember for peers from other cultures
- many workplaces simply respect their employees' desires to go by a name of their choosing, for whatever reasons apply

Naturally, we should be sympathetic to these needs; just because you might want your full name listed on your CV doesn't make it appropriate for day-to-day conversations with your team, much less *every* team that you might be a part of.

I'm told that the folks working on Stack Overflow for Teams have this issue high on their list of things to fix, and also that it is "Really Hard™".

So for now, I apologize for the inconvenience and lack of forethought in this area, and hope you'll be willing to give it another shot when eventually this is corrected.

Comment: Speaking as a programmer, I am boggled by the idea that making it possible to modify a property that is for display only, not structured in any way, and has no uniqueness requirement so can't be used as an identifier anywhere, would be “Really Hard™”.

Comment: I'm gonna assume that the hard bit here is designing a UI (perhaps that long-overdue "defaults and local overrides" thing we've been needing since '10?). A channel is in most ways just another site, sorta like child-metas but rather more integrated - so there's already a place to *store* the value, it just needs a plan for when that should/shouldn't sync with the parent. A sensible way to edit that without duplicating everything else may be a bit trickier.

Comment: Hi Shog, any idea when this will get fixed? It's pretty frustrating when so many other tasks have been held off so that devs could focus on teams only for them to leave this flaw in what they're focusing on.

Comment: I'm afraid I've no idea, @curiousdannii; I'll post an update here when I hear something.

Comment: Pinging again. Any movement?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It has "moved": https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/386450/1478931 :)

Answer (score 9):

This behaviour looks troublesome to me. Let's say I join a Team comprised of coworkers. In that case, a Team identity based on my real name that coexists with my older pseudonymous Stack Overflow identity should be an entirely natural thing to have. It shouldn't be necessary to give up one in order to have the other.

[This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364557/2751851) to a related question implies the tying in of identities is, at least in part, by design. [This other answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/368593/2751851) provides some further details and mentions plans to uncouple at least the full name from the Teams display name. It would be useful to know more about the odds of further mitigation measures.