# When signing up to teams, your profile pictures on other SE sites gets updated

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-for-teams, profile-picture

I recently joined a Stack Overflow Team. When I did, I confirmed my profile, and all was good....

Until I logged into chat, and my avatar had changed. My chat account is linked to my coffee.SE page, and has been for more than a year, with no changes. However the avatar on coffee.SE was changed to my team.SO avatar.

This shows up in the history log on my coffee.SE profile as 'user switched profile image to imgur'. This can only have been caused by the teams.SO sign up. (the IP is logged as `0.0.0.0`!)

I can't go back and check if there was a 'copy this information to every profile' option on the teams onboarding page - if there was it was checked by default - which I would consider to be wrong behaviour.

Comment: hmm, that sounds buggy. let me look into this and get back to you. thanks for the report!

Comment: See also: [*Joining a Team forces my Stack Overflow identity to match my real name*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/368334/2751851) (I'm not voting to close as a dupl\*cate because this question has a reply from a member of the Teams team).

Comment: @duplode Seems a slightly different issue. The linked q is saying that T.SO shouldn't update SO, which it does seemingly by design. However T.SO updating *.SE should definitely not be the case!

Comment: @fredley You are right -- this is even more surprising! Being optimistic, I'd wager the same underlying issue is involved, and that both problems will go away once it is dealt with. After all, if we have always been able to have varying user names and avatar across the different Network sites, it is hard to see why it shouldn't be the same with Teams.

Comment: Funky. I had changed my avatar on one of my teams at first, picking the one I use on Meta Stack Exchange instead of Stack Overflow. Upon noticing it caused my regular Stack Overflow avatar to change, I changed it back to my regular Stack Overflow avatar. I checked a bunch of satellite sites to see if it changed on those and none of those had changed. Wonder what the culprit is behind your change.

Comment: [This Question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364372/channels-overwrote-my-se-image-with-my-so-image) had the same issue, but that was marked Status completed. Looks like the bug still exists. Should these be marked as a duplicate then or not since the bug wasn't fixed?

Comment: @DavyM It's a new bug, or at least a regression of that fix, so it's best to leave it open. This question isn't solved by that answer, and vice versa, since this instance is ongoing.

Comment: @Kendra that's what I thought, thanks for confirming. Though I will of course leave the link so that whoever from the SO-Teams team who looks at this can see a solution was already attempted and did not work.

Comment: That's a regression. We "optimized" the way real names are kept in sync across the network and ended up also sync'ing profile images inadvertently. Only affects Teams users who also update their full names, in addition to their profile images. Working on it!

Comment: With respect to my previous comment, @DavyM 's link appears to confirm you're right about the SO-Teams coupling being by design, and about this being an independent issue.

Comment: I just joined Teams but my SO Profile still says JonH so not sure what happened with your case...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your report, this has now been fixed. While real name changes should be propagated across the SE network, profile images should not; we had fixed this issue [before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364372/channels-overwrote-my-se-image-with-my-so-image), but an attempt to make the code faster/cleaner resulted in all changes being broadcast inadvertently. Code is *slightly* uglier now but hey, it works!

Comment: Would you mind checking if this MSE report is related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/364557/578411

Comment: @rene yeah, that report was mentioned in the comments above, but it's a different bug. This one only impacted users who changed both their names and profile picture when joining a Team. The one you linked affected all users, even those who kept their name/image unchanged.